# Write to local data store in parse for android app

Tags: java, android, caching, parse-platform, local-storage

I read about local data storage for parse sdk android.
I have a arraylist with is stored in th local data store.
I creat a new parseobject wish be saved in the data base in parse after that i wont to add it to yhe arraylist to be accessible like the other parseobject when i lost connexion. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the docs:  https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#localdatastore

You could also use pinning (mentioned in the docs).  You can store multiple items in the local datastore but you would have to handle what would happen if they were not there.  Maybe this helps?....

Comment: But this dont explain haw to add parseobject to an arraylist in the local data or if it is possibl to make a similaire idea